# Svelte: Event forwarding on multiple levels

Tags: svelte-3

Dispatching an event using createEventDispatcher after the first time the event is handled the event forwarding stop, is there a way to dispatch the message on multiple level?

for example:
App.svelte

```
<script>
    import Outer from './Outer.svelte';

    function handleMessage(event) {
        alert(event.detail.value);
    }
</script>

<Outer on:message={handleMessage}/> // but I want it to also get handled here
```

Outer.svelte

```
<script>
    import Inner from './Inner.svelte';
    
    function handleMessage(event) {
        console.log(event.detail.text);
    }
</script>

<Inner on:message={handleMessage}/> // Here the object get handled for the first time?
```

Inner.svelte:

```
<script>
import {createEventDispatcher} from 'svelte';

const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();

function sayHello() {
 dispatch('message', {
  text: 'Hello!'
 });
}
</script>

<button on:click={sayHello}> // click this button the message get sent
 click to say hello
</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle and forward the event like this [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/ca59d458e0134baf97ec7c58ac31d8e0?version=3.51.0)

###### Outer.svelte

```
<Inner on:message={handleMessage} on:message/>
```